# adding document in global scope in typescript, accessible by node_module using require.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, global-variables

I'm still learning my way around typescript and have a script running in node.js which includes a node_module which requires access to a `document` and `XMLHttpRequest`.

My thinking was if I use `jsdom` which has typescript definitions, I would be able to create a global object which includes both `document` and `XMLHttpRequest`.

However, in my index file, I create

```
/// <reference path="./index.d.ts" />
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
document = jsdom('');
window = document.defaultView;
```

Where `index.d.tx` is

```
declare var document: Document;
declare var window: Window;
```

When I run my tests, the included node_module returns error
`ReferenceError: document is not defined`

I've seen and tried all manor of ways of defining global such as

```
export interface Global {
  document: Document;
  window: Window;
}

declare var global: Global;
```

and

```
declare module NodeJS  {
  interface Global {
      document: Document,
      window: Window
  }
}
```

the later of which allowed me to define in my index.ts

```
<reference path="./index.d.ts" />
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
document = jsdom('');
window = document.defaultView;

global.document = document;
global.window = window;
```

Unfortunately, no matter what I do, the `document` is not defined in the global namespace, and looking ahead, I'm going to need to be able to define `XMLHttpRequest` globally as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that you don't have the type properly defined in TypeScript - it's that Node is in strict mode and preventing you from creating a global variable by accident.

You are almost certainly running your version of node with `--use-strict` - you can either:

- Not run in strict mode

**or**

- Directly assign to `global` via `global.document = jsdom('');`, etc.

if you really need the global variable.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, I've added `NoImplicitUseStrict` to my tsconfig, but no change. I also added `global.document = jsdom('');` and I'm still getting the same error. Do I need to do either of these in combination with the above mentioned ts?

Comment: The problem is only in Node - the typings are necessary to help TS understand what's going on, but the runtime knows nothing of your types.  Remove the reference to `document` and `window` in your last snippet and leave just the `global.` assignments and things should just work (that is replace `document = jsdom(''); global.document = document` with `global.document = jsdom('');`)